# Casting in generics - Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, casting

I have a base class:

```
class ClassA {
    public prop1: string;
}
```

I have a generic interface:

```
interface IMyInterface<T extends ClassA> {
    objA: T;
}
```

And a generic class:

```
class MyClass<T extends ClassA> implements IMyInterface<T> {
    public objA: T;

    public myMethod () {
        this.objA.prop1 = "foo"; // This is ok

        if ("prop2" in this.objA) {
            this.objA.prop2 = "bar"; // This is not
        }
    }
}
```

How can  I force the `prop2` in `objA` if, and only if, this property exists in `objA`?

Do I have to force a cast as `(this.objA as ClassA & {prop2: string}).prop2 = "bar"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type guards, as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), inside the `Type Guards and Differentiating Types` session

Your code would be something like this:

```
class ClassA {
    public prop1: string;
}

interface IMyInterface<T extends ClassA> {
    objA: T;
}

interface IProp2 {
    prop2: string;
}

function hasProp2(obj: ClassA | IProp2): obj is IProp2 {
    return (<IProp2>obj).prop2 !== undefined;
}

class MyClass<T extends ClassA> implements IMyInterface<T> {
    public objA: T;

    public myMethod () {
        this.objA.prop1 = "foo"; // This is ok

        if (hasProp2(this.objA)){
            this.objA.prop2 = "bar"; // Now this is ok
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a current limitation of Typescript. I found [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) describing this exact case.

The workaround is the same as what you've already mentioned. You'll have to cast `this.objA` to some other type that permits setting a `prop2` field. So:

```
(this.objA as ClassA & {prop2: string}).prop2 = "bar"

// Or to trade some safety for brevity:
(this.objA as any).prop2 = "bar"
```

---

Otherwise, you can also use a custom type guard to assert the existence of that key. Using the one from the issue linked above, you can do something like this:

```
function inOperator<K extends string, T>(k: K, o: T): o is T & Record<K, any> {
    return k in o;
}
```

Then, using that instead of the `in` operator:

```
if (inOperator("prop2", this.objA)) {
    this.objA.prop2 = "bar"; // No error now
}
```